# How to get IP Address using phonegap javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How to get IP Address using phonegap javascript. I have to send this IP address to php page as a QueryString.

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Get what IP address? The IP of the phone? Can't you use the IP address the request came from?

Comment: Quentin , I have to send request after get IP.

Comment: Again - the IP of what? And if it is the IP of the client, then why do you have to get it and then included it in the request when the server will know the source ip of the request anyway?

Comment: How different is this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/15637384/744534

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2012/08/so-you-wanna-write-phonegap-200-android.html

Basically, you need to use a phonegap plugin that acts as a javascript wrapper and uses a method from the  native android SDK to get you the required IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Do not do any code in you Javascript ant send it to PHP page but in PHP page you can do the following function call to get the Real IP address...

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```