# tracker service.js file doesn't return address in phoneGap

Tags: android, html, angularjs, phonegap-desktop-app

So I have created a web-app and now I'm using **PhoneGap** to create the android application of my web-app. I followed all the steps in the phonegap tutorial. Also I'm using **oauth token** security. Currently I'm using the **phoneGap desktop** application and **weinre** debugger to see the log. Now I'm facing the following problem -

Part of my **tracker.service.js** code is as follows -

```
function connect () {
            var loc = $window.location;
            var url = '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname + 'websocket/tracker';
            var authToken = angular.fromJson($localStorage.authenticationToken).access_token;
            // the above code is to add a token as a security measure
            url += '?access_token=' + authToken;
           // ... rest of code ...
}
```

Now the above url is used to login the appllication. When I run this in the web-app everything is working fine as `$window.location` returns the ip-address of the current machine. But when I test it in my android phone, I am not able to login into the application.

When I checked in the debugger, I found out that `$window.location` was giving back the file path of the application in the system, as below

> ///data/user/0/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/index.htmlwebsocket/tracker?access_token=25a11f0a-1417-4454-b22b-456d0698798b

I don't know if while using in mobile `$window.location` returns the file path. If yes, than **is there any way that I get the ip-address and not the file path?**

Thanks.

Comment: there is some third parties to provide ip address of a mobile device please check them for your requirement

Comment: @SaEChowdary Can you give some names or references for these third parties?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637353/how-to-get-ip-address-in-jquery-or-phonegap-cross-platform