# How to get the IP address using PhoneGap and JavaScript without using server-side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working in [jQuery Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile) and [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) for iPhone and Android!!

In my application I need to find out the IP address of the mobile device and POST to the server to get the details of residence and currency details from the server as its result (in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format).

I created some code; but it contains an external link, **http://jsonip.appspot.com/?asp.net** and its code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function myIP() {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                else
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                xmlhttp.open("GET","http://jsonip.appspot.com/?asp.net",false);
                xmlhttp.send();

                hostipInfo = xmlhttp.responseText;
                obj = JSON.parse(hostipInfo);
                document.getElementById("IP").value = obj.ip;
                document.getElementById("ADDRESS").value = obj.address;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="myIP()">
        IP: <input type="text" id="IP" name="IP" />
        ADDRESS: <input type="text" id="ADDRESS" name="ADDRESS" />
    </body>
</html>
```

But I am looking for a solution without using any server-side calling (http://jsonip.appspot.com/?asp.net) and server-side coding. And only using JavaScript which is OK on mobile devices. Is there a solution for that?

Or do I need to follow the given example which I checked?

Comment: Your code worked perfectly? Whats the issue?

Comment: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2012/08/so-you-wanna-write-phonegap-200-android.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get IP Address using phonegap javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708330/how-to-get-ip-address-using-phonegap-javascript)

Comment: @Gajotres Please read my need before send its Duplicate Questions. i need without using external links..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708330/how-to-get-ip-address-using-phonegap-javascript is I also checkd before when i post Q in this!!

Comment: @Satpal I need to avoid the External links.. need to findout only using JavaScript and Client side !

Comment: @ULLASMOHAN.V You must either use a native plugin (the top-voted answer in the [proposed duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708330/how-to-get-ip-address-using-phonegap-javascript)) or server-side code. This cannot be done using only the current PhoneGap JavaScript APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed the device IP address as well.

It turns out there is a PhoneGap plugin that returns the device's IP address from the OS.

See https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/679 and https://github.com/salbahra/NetworkInterfacePlugin/ for source code.

I am posting this for people arriving via a search engine as it took me awhile to find the plugin.

Comment: from what I can tell this plugin just returns the ip address for the local wifi so something like 192...  I need the public ip for security auditing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){
        alert( data.host); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you real the part: `I created some code; but it contains an external link, http://jsonip.appsp...` and `...But I am looking for a solution without using any server-side calling`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(location) {
            alert(location.ip);
        }
    });
```

This will support https sites too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:
[how to edit local ip Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434383/how-to-edit-local-ip-address)

Function (proimse) findIP is what you are looking for.